# Prove this inequality with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}>0$, show that

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2\le \left(2+\dfrac{n}{4}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}$$

I can prove it when $2+\dfrac{n}{4}$  takes the place of $n$,

It seems we should use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: 
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos^2{k}\tag{1}$$

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2{k}\tag{2}$$
Adding $(1),(2)$ we have:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\cos^2{k}+\sin^2{k})=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}$$

Comment: Without the positivity constraint your bound would be close to optimal. For positive $x_k$ a sharp bound will be of the form $$\sum_{k=1}^n \max(0, \cos(k-\alpha))^2$$ for some angle $\alpha$. Intuitively this will indeed be “close” to $n/4$.

Comment: @WimC   Without the positivity constraint, i.e., $x\in R^n$, the upper bound seems to be $(\frac{n}{2} + c)\sum x_k^2$ for some constant $c$?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, you’re right.

Comment: Note: Expanding the sums in LHS yields the following expression:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 + 2\sum_{i < j} x_ix_j\cos(i - j)
$$

Comment: @Clemet Yung, so we need to estimate the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, where $a_{ij}=\cos(i-j)$? To be more precise, we need to prove that $\lambda_{max}\leq2+\frac{n}{4}$. Am I right?

Comment: @richrow   $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}} \le 2 +  \frac{n}{4}$ is not true.

Comment: @River Li, yes, I forget about the condition $x_i>0$.

Comment: The complex form of CS may be more helpful. The LHS is equal to $\bigl(\sum x_ke^{ik}\bigr)\bigl(\sum x_ke^{-ik}\bigr)$.

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: Now a full solution is given for $n \le 10^9$ (if this limitation is an issue at all, discussion and  possible extension see below).

Due to homogenity, the task is equivalent to the following: Find the maximum of the target function
$$
f(x) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2
$$
subject to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2 = {\rm{const.}}$, and then show that this maximum is less or equal than $\left(2+\dfrac{n}{4}\right)\cdot{\rm{const.}}$. In order to see which $x_k$ will generate this maximum, let's derive a necessary condition: At the maximum, consider changing two $x_k$'s, say $x_n$ and $x_m$, while keeping all other $x_k$ fixed. Then, for small changes $\delta x_n$, $\delta x_m$, since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2 = {\rm{const.}}$, the condition is 
$x_n \delta x_n = - x_m \delta x_m$. The change in the target function is 
$$
\delta f(x) = 2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)(\cos(n) \delta x_n + \cos(m) \delta x_m) +2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)(\sin(n) \delta x_n + \sin(m) \delta x_m)\\
= \left[ 2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)(\cos(n) - \cos(m) \frac{x_n}{x_m}) +2 \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)(\sin(n)  - \sin(m) \frac{x_n}{x_m}) \right] \delta x_n
$$
Since $\delta f(x)$ must be zero at the optimum, we have the condition that 
$$
\frac{x_n}{x_m} = \frac{
\cos(n) + a\sin(n)
}{
\cos(m) + a\sin(m)
} \qquad , {\rm{with }} \qquad a = \frac{
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos k} 
$$

Since this must hold for all pairs $(x_n, x_m)$, and since $x_k \ge 0$, the optimum is reached at
$x_k = \tilde c \cdot \max\{0, \cos(k) + a \sin(k)\}$, with an arbitrary constant $\tilde c$,  for all $x_k$, with $a$ to be fixed through the implicit equation $$a = \frac{
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos k}  $$
However this is inconclusive for $a$, see appendix A below. Hence we shall prove that such $x_k$ satisfy the inequality, for any $a$. The form of $x_k$ can equivalently be written  $x_k =c \cdot \max\{0, \sin(k + \phi)\}$, with an arbitrary constant $c$, and some angle $\phi$.

Note that the LHS of the inequality is, for any $x_k$,  $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{(k+\gamma)}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k+\gamma)}\right)^2$ with some arbitrary $\gamma$, which holds since $$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2 \\= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{m=1}^{n} x_k x_m
 \cos(k-m) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{m=1}^{n} x_k x_m
 \cos((k+\gamma)-(m+\gamma)) $$
Using this freedom, let us choose $\gamma = \phi$. Now we will estimate the two terms of the inequalty's LHS separately.

**Second term:** We have that
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k+\phi)}\right)^2 \le \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\max\{0, \sin(k + \phi)\}\right)^2
$$
Applied to the square we have
$(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)})^2 \le (\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\max\{0,\sin{(k + \phi)} \})^2$
and
$(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)})^2  = (-\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)})^2 \le (\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\min\{0,\sin{(k + \phi)} \})^2 $.

Either one of these inequalities is used, depending on whether  $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)} >0 $ or $<0$.

Applying Cauchy-Schwarz gives

$$
\frac{ (\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)})^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2}  \le \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\max\{0,\sin{(k + \phi)} \})^2  \\
= \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\sin{(k + \phi)} )^2 + \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^{n} |\sin{(k + \phi)}| \sin{(k + \phi)}
$$
or
$$
\frac{ (\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)})^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2}  \le \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\min\{0,\sin{(k + \phi)} \})^2  \\
= \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\sin{(k + \phi)})^2 - \frac12 \sum_{k=1}^{n} |\sin{(k + \phi)}| \sin{(k + \phi)}
$$
It has been shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499396) that, for any $\phi$, the second sum is $\le 1.75$. Further we have
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{n} (\sin{(k + \phi)})^2 |= |\frac{n}{2} + \frac{\sin(2\phi + 2 n + 1) )-\sin(2 \phi + 1) )}{4 (\sin(1))}| \le \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2 (\sin(1))}
$$
Combing the two limits we get for the second term:
$$\frac{ (\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{(k + \phi)})^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2}  \le
\frac{n}{4}+ 1.17$$
Note that the only condition used for the $x_k$ was their positivity.

**First term:** Now we use the particular form of the $x_k$. We have for the sum within the square, using the heaviside-function $\Theta(x)$:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{(k+\phi)} \le c \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos{(k+\phi)}\max\{0, \sin(k + \phi)\} \\
= \frac{c}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(2k+2\phi)}\Theta\{\sin(k + \phi)\}\\
=  \frac{c}{4} \left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(2k+2\phi)}
 + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sin{(2k+2\phi)}\Theta\{\sin(k + \phi)\}- \sin{(2k+2\phi)}\Theta\{-\sin(k + \phi)\})\right]
$$
For the first sum, we have 
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(2k+2\phi)}|= |\frac{\sin(n) \sin(2 \phi + n + 1)}{\sin(1)}| \le \frac{1}{\sin(1)} \le 1.19
$$
The second sum can be evaluated to be less than $\alpha =  2.4 +\frac{1}{2 \pi} (3\log(M + 1/2)) + \log(M - 3/2))   + \frac{8n}{\pi} \frac{M}{4M^2-1} $ for some $M \le 10^9$  (see appendix B). Combining the two, we have 
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{(k+\phi)}| \le 
  \frac{c}{4} \left[1.17  + \alpha\right]
$$
Further, we have analogously to the derivation above: 
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2 |= c^2|\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\max\{0,\sin{(k + \phi)} \})^2 |\ge c^2(\frac{n}{4}- 1.17)$$

This gives for the first term of the inequality's LHS, normalized to the length of $x$:

$$
\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{(k+\phi)})^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2} \\
\le 
\frac{(\frac{1}{4} \left[3.57 +\frac{1}{2 \pi} (3\log(M + 1/2)) + \log(M - 3/2))   + \frac{8n}{\pi} \frac{M}{4M^2-1} \right])^2}{\frac{n}{4}- 1.17}
\le
\frac{(\frac{1}{4} \left[3.57 +\frac{2}{ \pi} \log(M + 1/2)   + \frac{8n}{\pi} \frac{1}{3M} \right])^2}{\frac{n}{4}- 1.17}
$$
We have the freedom of choosing $M \le 10^9$, which we can use to minimize this expression. The minimum occurs at $M = 1/3 (\sqrt(2) \sqrt{(2 n^2 + 3 n)} + 2 n)$ so we choose $M = \frac{4 n }{3}$ which gives 
$$
\frac{(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{(k+\phi)})^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2} \\
\le
\frac{(\frac{1}{4} \left[3.57 +\frac{2}{ \pi} \log(\frac{4 n }{3} + 1/2)   + \frac{2}{\pi}  \right])^2}{\frac{n}{4}- 1.17}
\\
\le 
\frac{(\frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{2\log(n)}{ \pi} + \frac{2}{ \pi} \log(\frac{4 }{3} )   + \frac{2}{\pi}  + 3.57 \right])^2}{\frac{n}{4}- 1.17}
\\
\le 
\frac{(\frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{2\log(n)}{ \pi} + 4.4\right])^2}{\frac{n}{4}- 1.17} = \frac{\left[\frac{\log(n)}{ 8 \pi} + 0.275\right]^2}{\frac{n}{4}- 1.17}
$$
This result makes sense for reasonably large $n\ge 5$, which is an artefact of having to apply a lower bound for the denominator. This can be traeted if necessary. The result is strictly  falling with $n$, so we can bound it for $n\ge 5$by the result for $n =  6$ which is 0.36. This is a very rough bound, since for large $n$ this gets considerably smaller, already for $n=20$ we have 0.04. Note the result holds for $n \le 10^9$, if this is considered a limitation, it can be expanded (see appendix B).

Combining the two terms finally gives for the inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2 \le (\frac{n}{4}+ 1.54 )\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^2
$$

---

**Appendix A:**

Calculating  the implicit equation for $a$ gives inconclusive results, as will be shown here: 
$$a = \frac{
\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos k} =
\frac{
\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} (\cos(k) + a \sin(k))\sin{k}
}
{
\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} (\cos(k) + a \sin(k))\cos k
} \\
= \frac{
\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \cos(k) \sin{k} + a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \sin^2(k)
}
{
\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \cos(k) \sin{k} + a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \cos^2(k)
}\\
= \frac{
2\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \cos(k) \sin(k)  + a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} 1 {\color{red}+} a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0}(\sin^2(k) - \cos^2(k))
}
{
2\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \cos(k) \sin(k) + a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} 1 {\color{red}-} a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0}(\sin^2(k) - \cos^2(k))
}\\
= \frac{
\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \sin(2 k)+ a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} 1 {\color{red}-} a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \cos(2 k)
}
{
\sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} \sin(2 k) + a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0} 1 {\color{red}+} a \sum_{k ; \cos(k) + a \sin(k) > 0}\cos(2 k)
}$$
Since, for large $n$,   $\sum_{k ; \cos(k) +  \sin(k) > 0}\cos(2 k)$ is of the same order as $\sum_{k ; \cos(k) +  \sin(k) > 0} 1 $, this gives no clear indication of $a$. The inituitive $a\simeq 1$ does not hold, as the following example shows, which was generated through computer search to find, for varying $n$ and $a$, the highest value of $$\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}} - \frac{n}{4}$$ The result is:

Let $a = 6.47$ and $n=10256$, then setting $x_k = \max\{0, \cos(k) + a \sin(k)\}$ gives

$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cos{k}\right)^2+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\sin{k}\right)^2\le \left({\color{red}{1.0466}}+\dfrac{n}{4}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}
$$

Since $n$ is large, this shows the leading proportionality to $n/4$.

**Appendix B:** For the sum 
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sin{(2k+2\phi)}\Theta\{\sin(k + \phi)\}- \sin{(2k+2\phi)}\Theta\{-\sin(k + \phi)\})
$$
we use the following Fourier series representation:
$$
\sin{(2x)}\Theta\{\sin(x)\}- \sin{(2x)}\Theta\{-\sin(x)\}\\
= \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{-8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4} \cos((2m+1)x)
$$
This  allows us to write
$$
S_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{-8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos((2m+1)(k+\phi))\\
= \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{-8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4}  \frac{\sin((m + 1/2) n) \cos(1/2 (2 m + 1) (n + 2 \phi + 1))}{\sin(m + 1/2) }
$$
Now we have the following fact which can be evaluated by computer: we have that
$\frac{1}{|\sin(m + \frac12)|}<m$ for almost all $m \in [2,10^9]$, other than very few exceptions, i.e. $m_R \in \{9,12,166,188, 51996, 156344,990063,2136471,40071928,205778993\}$.

Note 1: if this limitation(which we will also apply to $n$)  is an issue at all, it can be verified by computer for higher terms as well, with few exceptions which do not hamper the overall result.

Note 2: The bound can be further tightened, see Jack D'Aurizio's answer in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930375) which discusses $\frac{1}{\left|\sin m\right|}\leq \frac{\pi/2}{d(m,\pi\mathbb{Z})}$.

This allows to write, with $M \le 10^9$:

$$
S_n =  \frac{1}{\pi}[\sum_{m=0}^{1} +\sum_{m=2}^{M-1} + \sum_{m=M}^\infty] \frac{-8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4}\frac{\sin((m + 1/2) n) \cos(1/2 (2 m + 1) (n + 2 \phi + 1))}{\sin(m + 1/2) }
$$
The first two terms evaluate
$$
|S_n^{(1)}| \le  \frac{1}{\pi} (\frac{8}{3 |\sin(\frac12)|} + \frac{8}{5 |\sin(\frac32)|} ) \le 2.28
$$
For  the second part, we bound
$$
|S_n^{(2)}| =  \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{m=2}^{M-1}  | \frac{8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4} \frac{1}{ \sin(m + \frac12)}|
\\
\le \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{m=2}^{M-1} | \frac{m}{(2m+1)^2 - 4} | + \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{m_R}  |\frac{8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4}(\frac{1}{ \sin(m_R + \frac12)} -m_R)| \\
\le \frac{8}{\pi} \int_{m=2}^{M-1} | \frac{m}{(2m+1)^2 - 4} | + \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{m_R}  |\frac{8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4}(\frac{1}{ \sin(m_R + \frac12)} -m_R)| \\
\le \frac{1}{2 \pi} (3\log(M + 1/2)) + \log(M - 3/2))  + \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{m_R}  |\frac{8}{(2m+1)^2 - 4}(\frac{1}{ \sin(m_R + \frac12)} -m_R)| \
$$
The third part can be bounded, using that $\frac{\sin(n(m + \frac12)) }{ \sin(m + \frac12)} \le n$, with
$$
|S_n^{(3)}| =  \frac{8 n }{\pi} \sum_{m=M}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{(2m+1)^2 - 4}
\\
\le \frac{8n}{\pi} |\frac{M}{4M^2-1} |
$$

and altogether
$$
|S_n| \le 2.4 +\frac{1}{2 \pi} (3\log(M + 1/2)) + \log(M - 3/2))   + \frac{8n}{\pi} \frac{M}{4M^2-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Under what circumstances it is verified that the eigenvalues ​​of

$$
Q_n = a_n\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 -\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\sin k\right)^2-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\cos k\right)^2
$$

are all non-negative?

$$
Q_n = X^{\dagger}M_n X
$$

where

$$
M_n = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
       a_n-1 & -\cos (1) & \cdots & -\cos (n-2) & -\cos (n-1) \\
 -\cos (1) &       a_n-1 & \cdots & -\cos (n-3) & -\cos (n-2) \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 -\cos (n-2) & -\cos (n-3) & \cdots & a_n-1       & -\cos (1) \\
 -\cos (n-1) & -\cos (n-2) & \cdots & -\cos (1) & a_n-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The $M_n$ eigenvalues are

$$
\{a_1-1\}\\
\{a_2-1-\cos (1),a_2-1+\cos (1)\}\\
\{a_3,a_3-2-\cos (2),a_3-1+\cos (2)\}\\
\{a_4,a_4,a_4-2-\cos (3)-\cos (1),a_4-2+\cos (3)+\cos (1)\}\\
\{a_5,a_5,a_5,a_5-3-\cos (4)-\cos(2),a_5-2+\cos (4)+\cos (2)\}\\
\{a_6,a_6,a_6,a_6,a_6-3-\cos (5)-\cos (3)-\cos (1),a_6-3+\cos (5)+\cos (3)+\cos (1)\}\\
\{a_7,a_7,a_7,a_7,a_7,a_7-4-\cos (6)-\cos (4)-\cos(2),a_7-3+\cos (6)+\cos (4)+\cos (2)\}\\
\{a_8,a_8,a_8,a_8,a_8,a_8,a_8-4-\cos (7)-\cos (5)-\cos (3)-\cos (1),a_8-4+\cos (7)+\cos(5)+\cos (3)+\cos(1)\}\\
\{a_9,a_9,a_9,a_9,a_9,a_9,a_9,a_9-5-\cos (8)-\cos (6)-\cos (4)-\cos (2),a_9-4+\cos (8)+\cos(6)+\cos (4)+\cos (2)\}\\
\vdots
$$

and the conditions on $a_n$ such that all the eigenvalues are positive

$$
a_1 > 1\\
a_2 > 1+\cos(1)\\
a_3 > 1+\cos(2)\\
a_4 > 2-\cos (1)-\cos (3)\\
a_5 > 2-\cos (2)-\cos (4)\\
a_6 > 3-\cos (1)-\cos (3)-\cos (5)\\
a_7 > 4+\cos (2)+\cos (4)+\cos (6)\\
a_8 > 4+\cos (1)+\cos (3)+\cos (5)+\cos (7)\\
a_9 > 5+\cos (2)+\cos (4)+\cos (6)+\cos (8)\\
\vdots
$$

Follows a plot showing in blue $\{a_k\}$ and in red $\{2+\frac k4\}$

[image]

As we can observe, for $k \le 6$ the factor $\color{red}{(2+\frac k4)}$ is well placed but for $k \ge 7$ remains a strong doubt. In green a factor which agrees with the eigenvalues positiveness. $\color{green}{(\frac 23+\frac k2)}$

Comment: Without the positivity constraint, $\frac{n}{2}+c$ is easily obtained for some constant $c$.